# Laravel - How to do a specific query with query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm using Laravel and have a very specific query that I don't know how to implement with query builder.

The query:

```
SET @c_num=0;

SELECT *, @c_num:=@c_num+1 AS 'COUNT' 
FROM table_name 
WHERE USERID = 2
ORDER BY id
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
DB::statement(DB::raw('SET @c_num = 0'));

$result = DB::table('table_name')
    ->selectRaw("*, @c_num:=@c_num+1 AS 'COUNT'")
    ->where('userid', 2)
    ->orderBy('id')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = DB::table('table_name')
->where('userid',2)
->select('table_name.*',DB::raw('(@c_num:=@c_num+1) Count')
->orderBy('id')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
DB::table('table_name')
    ->selectRaw("*, @c_num:=IF(@c_num, @c_num+1, 1) as 'COUNT'")
    ->where('user_id', 2)
    ->orderBy('id');
```